# Best way to run Flutter apps on Windows/Linux from Android Studio on Parallels for MacOS?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, parallels

I'm using Android Studio to do my Flutter development on my M1 Macbook Air, and so far it's been easy running the app through the macOS/iOS/Android simulators. I want to next try it on Windows and Linux machines.

I just downloaded Parallels to try that out running windows and linux. What's the best way to test on those machines?

I'm guessing I need to install Android Studio on both of those machines (Or maybe vscode?), get the code (git repo maybe) and then run it there?

Is there a better way?